# ¿Cómo especifico las características que quiero mantener en un diccionario y agrupar todas las demás?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, json

Tengo un diccionario con los resultados de partidos en una elecion y me gustaria crear un csv a partir de el.

```
Constituency,PI,PJD,PAM,USFP,Other parties
NA-1,30,32,0,26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12
NA-2,45,38,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17
```

Es decir, para cada circunscripción, los resultados en percentaje por partidos en una lista, y esto para cada `constituency`.

Aqui esta el archivo JSON relacionado:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "fd597jf1799.1",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.27163887,
                33.24041367
              ],
              [
                -7.27163887,
                33.24041367
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152,
        "iso": "MAR",
        "name_0": "Morocco",
        "id_1": 1,
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha",
        "id_2": 1,
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_3": 1,
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_4": 1,
        "name_4": "Ahlaf",
        "varname_4": null,
        "ccn_4": 0,
        "cca_4": null,
        "type_4": "Commune Rural",
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune",
        "bbox": [
          -7.27286911,
          33.22112656,
          -6.93353081,
          33.38970184
        ],
        "swing_count": 1,
        "polling_station_count": 15,
        "turnout": 0.4780299144225693,
        "results": {
          "PI": 187,
          "PJD": 88,
          "PAM": 59,
          "USFP": 1530,
          "APFGD": 2,
          "PPS": 15,
          "RNI": 708,
          "MP": 56,
          "UC": 3,
          "FFD": 0,
          "MDS": 0,
          "AAR": 0,
          "P Neo-Democrates": 8,
          "PEDD": 0,
          "PRD": 2,
          "PRV": 0,
          "PDI": 0,
          "PGVM": 0,
          "PALAMAL": 0,
          "PCS": 0,
          "PUD": 0,
          "PDN": 1,
          "PLJS": 0,
          "PSD": 0,
          "P Annahda": 0,
          "PA": 0,
          "UMD": 0,
          "USAPMD": 10
        },
        "voter_file": {
          "nbre_sieges": 3,
          "nbre_inscrits": 5953,
          "nbre_votants": 2997,
          "nbre_nuls": 328,
          "nbre_exprimees": 2669
        },
        "swing_ratio": 0.06666666666666667
      }
    },
    {"type": "Feature", 
    "id": "fd597jf1799.5", 
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon", 
      "coordinates": [[[[-7.10879707, 33.63715363], [-7.10618496, 33.6385231]]]]}, 
      "geometry_name": "geom", 
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152, 
        "iso": "MAR", 
        "name_0": "Morocco", 
        "id_1": 1, 
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha", 
        "id_2": 1, 
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane", 
        "id_3": 1, 
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane", 
        "id_4": 5, 
        "name_4": "Moualine El Ghaba", 
        "varname_4": None, 
        "ccn_4": 0, 
        "cca_4": None, 
        "type_4": "Commune Rural", 
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune", 
        "bbox": [-7.25548506, 33.53932571, -7.01937389, 33.7419014],
        "swing_ratio": 0.0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Por lo momento intenté:

```
>>> d = []
>>> j=0
>>> for feature in dct['features']:
...     j+=1
...     r={"Constituency": "MAR - " + str(j)}
...     for key,value in feature.get("properties",{}).get("results", {}).items():
...          r[key] = value
...     d.append(r)
...
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df.set_index("Constituency", inplace = True)
>>> cols = df.columns
>>> df[cols] = df[cols] = df[cols].div(df[cols].sum(axis = 1), axis = 0).multiply(100)
```

Pero una maneja de decir cuales son los partidos que deben aparecer en la DataFrame:

```
>>> df.head()
                     PI       PJD       PAM       USFP     APFGD        PPS        RNI         MP        UC  FFD  MDS  AAR  ...  PDI  PGVM  PALAMAL  PCS  PUD       PDN  PLJS  PSD  P Annahda   PA       UMD     USAP
MD
Constituency                                                                                                                ...

MAR - 1        7.006369  3.297115  2.210566  57.324841  0.074934   0.562008  26.526789   2.098164  0.112402  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0   0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.037467   0.0  0.0        0.0  0.0  0.000000   0.3746
72
MAR - 2       45.515362  9.068385  3.543112   0.545094  1.090188  19.152626   2.700694   2.750248  0.222993  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0   0.0      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.024777   0.0  0.0        0.0  0.0  0.049554  12.7353
82
```

Estoy apprendido el javascript. Estaría igual de satisfecho en ese lenguaje

Comment: Es decir, lo que deseas es mostrar el contenido de tu clave results como una tabla CSV??